# How can I get the patterns spotted by bzip2? (or any other compression algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, compression

I have a huge file made up of the characters "0", "1", "2", "3". No spaces, not anything else. Just these 4 characters. I have used bzip2 to compress it and the file decreased size from X to 0.05*X. I'd like to know what were the strings/patterns that bzip2 found to achieve that compressed version of the file (e.g. 0123213232, 0123121212222112, etc.). Is there a simple way to extract that information either from the actual bz2 file or by running bzip2 with some special command-line option?

If you know the answer for some other existing compression program, I'll also be interested in hearing about that.

Thanks for any help.

Best,
Surikator.

Answer (score 3):

Bzip2 uses Burrows-Wheeler transform to turn repeated byte sequences into sequences of the same byte in a reversible way. Then it uses the [move-to-front](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move-to-front_transform) algorithm to transform repeated bytes to zero sequences. After that it uses [huffmann coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) to assign shorter symbols to more frequent bytes (probably the zeros). You can find more details on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2#Compression_stack).

Comment: For some strange reason I can't add this link to my answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows–Wheeler_transform Ahh and it points to the wrong place if you click it.

Comment: This works (got it by right-clicking on the "Article" tab): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform

Comment: I guess you mean 'shorter symbols' rather than 'sorter symbols' (i.e. fewer bits as shown in Margus' answer in the 'new binary' column).

Answer (score 1):

bzip2 doesn't have an option for this, and it doesn't work exactly like I think you think it works.  Regardless, you can find code for the various pieces in the algorithm.  As @stribika mentioned, it uses the Burrows-Wheeler and move to front algorithms before pumping it through a Huffman encoder.  Google should get you some results for a Burrow's Wheeler transform in the language of your choice.

However, based on what you're looking for, I think you want more of a dictionary style encoder.  You might be interested in an LZW algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch

It will build up a dictionary of strings like you showed.

Comment: And there are source files on the official site. It's simple to add some `printf()` s to them.

Comment: On the official bzip2 site?  I'm sure there's C source there.  I also found an Ocaml implementation of the Burrows Wheeler transform.  Google can get you that.

Answer (score 1):

### Burrows-Wheeler transform

It is also called **block-sorting**. If you do not like reading Wikipedia, then read Mathematical foundations of computer science 1999: http://books.google.ee/books?id=OcJjpqAi15EC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=mathematica+Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler+transform&source=bl&ots=KaOOIPJcKC&sig=5PzHG9UQeg3opr1FUMq8mPAxfn4&hl=et&ei=Y6vPTLfVFsqCOozvvPcE&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

### Huffman coding

For a input of: `"this is an example of a huffman tree"`. Binary tree like this is built:

[image]

It is then used to build coding table:

```
 Char ' ' nr(32)    | binary:00100000 | new binary:111
 Char 'a' nr(97)    | binary:01100001 | new binary:001
 Char 'e' nr(101)   | binary:01100101 | new binary:000
 Char 'f' nr(102)   | binary:01100110 | new binary:1101
 Char 'h' nr(104)   | binary:01101000 | new binary:1100
 Char 'i' nr(105)   | binary:01101001 | new binary:1001
 Char 'l' nr(108)   | binary:01101100 | new binary:01101
 Char 'm' nr(109)   | binary:01101101 | new binary:1000
 Char 'n' nr(110)   | binary:01101110 | new binary:1011
 Char 'o' nr(111)   | binary:01101111 | new binary:01100
 Char 'p' nr(112)   | binary:01110000 | new binary:01111
 Char 'r' nr(114)   | binary:01110010 | new binary:01110
 Char 's' nr(115)   | binary:01110011 | new binary:1010
 Char 't' nr(116)   | binary:01110100 | new binary:0101
 Char 'u' nr(117)   | binary:01110101 | new binary:01001
 Char 'x' nr(120)   | binary:01111000 | new binary:01000
```

New binary can only be read, if you have the same tree, so that is also backed in output. Also length of the data is store, because sum of new binary's is not full byte number.

### Open software

You can just read

- manual pages: http://www.bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2-manual-1.0.5.html
- or source : http://www.bzip.org/1.0.6/bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz